# Exclude value if under a certain percentage

Tags: php, cakephp, chart.js

I am trying to make a pie chart, using chartjs, to display almost all the data in a database. What it does is count how many times a certain word is used in the database and it uses that count as the value and the word as the name.

In my pie chart I have almost 10 values that are about .01% of the pie chart and i'm trying to remove them.

Anyone have any ideas?

Also google searching this makes it seem like chartjs is not that popular nor supported, would it be more reasonable to use something else?

EDIT:

cakephp MODEL:

```
function pieChart($conditions = null) {
    //Get Data for PieChart
    $this->RecordDrug->virtualFields['sum'] ='COUNT(*)';
    $records = array();
    $records=$this->RecordDrug->find('list',
        array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'fields' => array( 'Drug.drug', 'sum'),
            'contain' => array( 'Drug', 'Record' ),
            'group'  => 'Drug.Drug'
            ));
    return $records;
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    $pieChart = $this->Record->pieChart();
    $this->set('output',$pieChart);
```

VIEW:

```
   var pieChartDataSource = [
        <?php
        foreach($output as $compound => $sum){
          echo "{category: '".$compound."', value: ".$sum."}, ";
        }      
        ?>      
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to filter your dataset before calling chartjs to create the chart. Is there any reason not to do that?

Comment: Well that was kind of my question, how to do that

Comment: Can you please post the code that creates your dataset and calls chartjs?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sumofvars=array_sum($output);
$above_percent=0.1;

    foreach($output as $compound => $sum){

$percentage_to_eliminate=($sum/$sumofvars)*100;

if ($percentage_to_eliminate>$above_percent)
{

 echo "{category: '".$compound."', value: ".$sum."}, ";

}

    }      
    ?>      
];
```

Comment: This looks perfect, the only problem is I really have no idea how to implement this into cakephp

Comment: i have never used cakephp, but what is the code you use now to output data for chart